# MAMP avoid index file opening by default

Tags: mamp

Just a quick question concerning MAMP.
When going through the hard drive through the "localhost command" in my browser, upon opening a folder which contains a index.html file, how to stay in file browsing mode without it rendering the index file right away? Its a fresh MAMP install, the only setting I made was redefine my "Username/Sites" folder as localhost.

Answer (score -1):

Locate following line in httpd.conf in your MAMP folder:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Remove index.html and restart MAMP.

See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex